# Why can only forms be referenced by dot notation?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, syntax

It seems like a simple beginners question, but I'm unable to find an answer anywhere.

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="myTxt">
</form>
```

then I can use the following javascript

```
document.myForm.myTxt.value = 'foo';
```

But what if I have a div instead of a form?

```
<div name="myDiv">
   <span name="mySpan"></span>
</div>
```

Why can't I do the same thing here, like

```
document.myDiv.mySpan.innerHTML = "bar";
```

Seems like it should be possible to do, instead of having to use getELementById(), but I can't make it work.

Comment: Because Javascript was designed to handle forms that way.

Comment: "name" isn't valid for divs, spans, or most other page elements.

Comment: Marking as off-topic since according to the FAQ — *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face* — and this is a question about history. (The answer is *probably* that the forms collection exists as a legacy of the early days of DOM 0 before DOM 1 was designed with the benefits of hindsight, but that's a guess)

Comment: To answer your problem, `document.getElementById()`, as it says, looks for `id` attributes, not `name` (as well as the other commentary on validity of attributes).

Comment: @Quentin This is practical, answerable, and appears to be based on an actual problem. There's nothing wrong with a question about history.

Comment: @JohnKugelman — What is practical about "Why was DOM 0 designed this way?"?

Comment: @Quentin: If I read your comment correctly, it sounds like the *answer* would be about history, but not so much the question.

Comment: I think what @Quentin is getting at (and I agree), *does anyone really know*? This will probably generate a lot of speculation along the lines he's suggested (my thoughts, too, probably just legacy based on imperfect design). Unless there's a *canonical* explanation by or attributed to an authority, it's conjecture.

Comment: That's right, maybe I should have omitted the "Why" in the question. What I really anted to know is if it is possible to do. Guess not. But it would be quite convienint, wouldn't it?

Comment: (My opinion) No, it's not really necessary. Once `document.querySelector` and it's ilk gets wide browser functionality, it's not really necessary in combination with `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`. jQuery and other libraries were designed to abstract the verbosity. But technically, `document.form(s)` should probably be deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As designed by W3C.

There's really nothing to argue about. You can access the an HTMLCollection of all the forms on the page through `document.forms`, much like you can images with `document.images`, applets with `document.applets`, links with `document.links` and anchors with `document.anchors`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064

Comment: I think that list of DOM nodes is appropriate to describe a *possible* reason: Early browsers were *simple* and documents were *simple*. *`document.applets`*? (Facetiously...) Really?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you've posted is for form, to be specific.. It will work only with forms..

You will need to use following line to make it work for divs...

```
document.getElementsByName("myDiv")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "bar";
```

There are other ways to do this too...

Comment: Seems like getElementsByTagName only works on document, not lower level elements.

Comment: Nope.. It works on `Element` (interface `HTMLElement`). The reason you can't directly chain these functions is because `getElementsByTagName` returns `HTMLCollection`, which is a collection of `HTMLElement`s - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element