# A JS exception caused by 'form' element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tagname

Today I ran into this problem and it annoys me a lot...
I'm maintaining a JS project and there's a line:

```
node.tagName
```

where `node.nodeType` is `1`.
Obviously the code wants to get the tag name of this element and it seems to work fine for 99.99% webpages...

Sadly, when I execute the script on http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/377/D, it doesn't work. The reason is that there's a `form` element with a child node which has property `name="tagName"`.
[image]

Child nodes of `form` element who have property `name` can be accessed like:`node.NAME_VALUE`([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020289/why-can-only-forms-be-referenced-by-dot-notation)), so `node.tagName` will get its child whose name property is `tagName` rather than the node's tag name `form`.

Does anyone ever run into this problem, too? Are there any other solutions except checking whether the node is `form`?

---

**EDIT 1:**
I've fired a bug for jQuery [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14667). I did this because it may be much easier for jQuery to fix this for `.prop("tagName")` than making all browsers solve this issue.
BTW, I think no one should use something like `tagName` or `nodeName` as an HTMLInputElement's `name` value.

Comment: You overriding `tagName` property of Node.

Comment: I would suggest to not use tagName directly, rather to "find" the element whose name is "tagName" it is more secure, and more widely accepted in browsers

Comment: @Givi Sounds a little bit complicated for me but worth trying.

Comment: @Givi would overriding it even help here?  Or would node.NAME_VALUE (when NAME_VALUE == "tagName") still take precedence?

Comment: @nrathaus Why? Would be better avoid using Node property names as value of input name or id attributes, and how you use event delegation without tagName?

Comment: Many of these "shortcuts" don't work properly, for example className doesn't work in i.e. and you need to use setAttribute('class', ..). So I suggest to always avoid it and use thing like getAttribute('name') to find the element you seek, or use jQuery to handle this hassle for you

Comment: Amare just use different value for name or id attributes and that's all.

Comment: @nrathaus I'm sorry but I don't think you understand my question... I want to get the tag name of an element, such as `input`,`form`,`div`, but using `node.tagName` won't give me that if the node is `form` and its child has property `name=tagName`.

Comment: You can alternatively use `document.getElementById("addTagForm").toString();` that will return "[object HTMLFormElement]" or `document.getElementById("addTagForm").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("form")`

Comment: @Givi thanks for your help, I'll modify my code to use `nodeName` right now... I'll never use `tagName` as property `name`'s value...

Comment: interesting...  jQuery has this same problem when using `.prop("tagName")`

Comment: `tagName` is a problematic element, in some cases it will return `A` and in some cases it will return `a` ( "a" will be "A" in HTML pages, and "a" in XHTML pages ) so I think `nodeType` is a better thing to do here as the first step and then use toLower() to make sure you always get the right name

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on these things, so this may not be the best answer you could get, but never the less... i can think of two solutions:

1) Use nodeName instead if you can be certain that input name will not exist.

2) Use `element.clone(false).tagName` (such as `document.getElementById('someid').clone(false).tagName`)

Answer (score 0):

If `node.tagName` does not work for you, use `node.nodeName`.

I use`node.nodeName` in my code.